# ESP32 with battery (and display ?)

Tags: esp32

I would like to play around with ESP32, as I sense it might be the answer to my [previous question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10368/off-the-shelf-cheap-wearable-bluetooth-low-energy-device) .

I would like something which is battery powered, can be extremely low powered, as battery life is my key concern (so, I imagine that I would be better off using BLE than WiFi (?))).

I won’t be using any GPIO, although it might be nice to have for a display or development (possibly even for the final product, depending on the effect on battery life (the display would not be constantly active, only occasionally, as needed, maximum one minute per hour)). I suppose some sort of buzzer/vibrator wouldn’t hurt, but it’s “nice to have” at best.

I would prefer programming in C (actually, I would prefer Ada, but that’s not likely), and could live with Python. A good IDE is a must have. In case of a tie,  support will play a role, as will price.

I will be using it for tracking in an industrial setting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at Adafruit's ESP32 based offerings?

Comment: Yes, and SparkFun.There.' goo info [here](https://makeradvisor.com/esp32-development-boards-review-comparison/), but I was hoping for something more covfefe